Custom Numeric Iterator Implementation
So I have this structure for my own datatypes:
public class VOID : object
    {
        public dynamic value;
        public dynamic subvalue;

        public VOID(dynamic _value = null, dynamic _subvalue = null)
        {
            if (_value is null)
            {
                _value = "VOID";
            }

            this.value = _value;

            if (_subvalue is null)
            {
                _subvalue = "NULL";
            }

            this.subvalue = _subvalue;
        }
}

public class natch64 : VOID
    {
        public const double DefaultValue = 0D;
        public const double MaxValue = 18446744073709551615D;
        public const double MinValue = 0D;

        public natch64(ulong _value) : base(_value)
        {
            if (_value > natch64.MaxValue)
            {
                Natch64OutOfRangeMaxError er = new Natch64OutOfRangeMaxError(0, 0);
                this.value = natch64.DefaultValue;
            }
            else if (_value < natch64.MinValue)
            {
                NatchOutOfRangeOtricError er = new NatchOutOfRangeOtricError(0, 0);
                this.value = natch64.DefaultValue;
            }
            else
            {
                this.value = Convert.ToULong(_value);
            }
        }
}

public class drobch64 : VOID
    {
        public const double DefaultValue = 0D;
        public const double MaxValue = 18446744073709551615D;
        public const double MinValue = -9223372036854775807D;

        public drobch64(double _value) : base(_value)
        {
            switch (_value)
            {
                case > drobch64.MaxValue :
                {
                    Drobch64OutOfRangeMaxError er = new Drobch64OutOfRangeMaxError(0, 0);
                    this.value = drobch64.DefaultValue;
                    break;
                }
                case < drobch64.MinValue :
                {
                    Drobch64OutOfRangeMinError er = new Drobch64OutOfRangeMinError(0, 0);
                    this.value = drobch64.DefaultValue;
                    break;
                }
                default :
                    this.value = Convert.ToDouble(_value);
                    break;
            }
        }
}

All operator overloads to System datatypes work perfectly fine. And a custom typed ArrayList class (I know its not the most efficient but I need ArrayList:
public class massiv<Type> : VOID
    {
        public ulong MaxLength = 4294967295U;
        public natch64 Count = new natch64(0);

        public massiv() : base()
        {
            this.value = new ArrayList();
        }

        public massiv(natch64 _value) : base(_value)
        {
            if (this.Count.value <= this.MaxLength)
            {
                this.value = new ArrayList { new natch64(_value) };
            }
            else
            {
                this.value = new MassivOutOfRangeError(0, 0);
            }
        }

        public massiv(drobch64 _value) : base(_value)
        {
            if (this.Count.value <= this.MaxLength)
            {
                this.value = new ArrayList { new drobch64(_value.value) };
            }
            else
            {
                this.value = new MassivOutOfRangeError(0, 0);
            }
        }


All basic adding, removing from end of my array and indexing works.
My question is how do I make the following 3 lines of code work:
massiv<Type> = new massiv(Type[] {1, 2, 3, 4});

foreach (Type i in mymassiv)
{
    //spits out a ith element
} 

foreach (natch64 i in (natch64)10)
{
    //spits out a numbers 0 to 10 not inclusive of 10
} 

foreach (drobch64 i in (drobch64)10.0)
{
    //spits out a numbers 0 to 10 not inclusive of 10 with a step epsilon = 0.000001
} 


You don't. You use the proper C# syntax and implement the proper interfaces instead, eg use slicing to return the first 10 items with mycollection[0..10]. C# doesn't allow you to create custom operators or change the language. That's what F# is for, which already has a void type called unit. foreach isn't a method of your type so you can't change the way it works from your type.

.NET 7 introduced static abstract operators which allowed creating common arithmetic interfaces like IAdditionOperators<TSelf,TOther,TResult>, IBinaryInteger, IFloatingPoint. It's unclear what you want to do but if you want to create a new numeric type, look at these interfaces.

Is this code relevant:
´´´
public struct Pair: IEnumerable
{
public Pair(T first, T second) : this()
{
First = first;
Second = second;
}
public T First { get; }
public T Second { get; }
#region IEnumerable
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
yield return First;
yield return Second;
}
#endregion IEnumerable
#region IEnumerable Members
System.Collections.IEnumerator
System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
return GetEnumerator();
}
#endregion
// ...
}
´´´
?

What are you trying to do? You can't change how C# works. You can't define your own  custom operators. Some of the things you ask are already available out of the box. And while people hijacked IEnumerator in the past to eg create asynchronous interfaces before async/await was introduced, that's no longer necessary. Hijacking IEnumerator was costly too, because a new enumerator has to be created each time

@PanagiotisKanavos I’m trying to Hijack C# for the example above to work

To do what? You didn't provide an example of what you want, only how you assume it could work. Which isn't possible.

Are you trying to create collections larger than 2B items? There are libraries for this and built-in vectorization support that uses the CPU's SIMD registers. What you try to do would result in horrible performance because it could result in millions if not billions of enumerator instances that have to be garbage collected, and take more RAM than the data itself. That's what the libraries avoid. Performance depends heavily on CPU caching and data locality too (think multiples, not percentages). Numeric libraries take care of this as well

There are several identical questions by the way like this one, and implementations going at least as far back as BigArrayOfLong. At least one way is to create an array of arrays. The problem though isn't indexing at all. RAM access isn't uniform, and hasn't been for over 30 years. CPU caching means that processing data that's already in cache is a lot faster than going to RAM. And that was before NUMA and multi-core architectures.

Also the use of dynamic, this is a great way to destroy performance, and is mostly useful in a few narrow niches. You should really explain what the overall purpose of all this is, because it really smells like an XY-problem.

You don't need the IList<T>.Item operator to create a large array either. You can create your own GetValue and SetValue methods that use the built-in BigInteger type for an index.
